# How to convert hex to decimal in Actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How to convert hex(in string) to decimal(int) in Actionscript3?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Number`, `int` and `uint` class having `toString()` method which accept `radix` as arguments.

`radix` Specifies the numeric base (from 2 to 36) to use for the number-to-string conversion. If you do not specify the radix parameter, the default value is 10.

you can convert to any base like octal, hex, binary via Number and uint class.

Better way

`var decimal:int =  parseInt("FFFFFF",16);`   // output : 16777215

Another way

```
var hex:String = "0xFFFFFF";
```

`var hexint:int = int(hex);`  // output : 16777215

it is equivalent to

`var hexint:int = int(hex).toString(10);` //Decimal conversion

Back to original value :

```
var decimalStr:String = hexint.toString(16).toUpperCase(); // output : FFFFFF
```

Comment: if I have a 95 (without 0x) in the string. do i need to concat 0x and 95 first? is it a common practice?

Comment: Note that the top level functions [parseInt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#parseInt()) and [parseFloat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#parseFloat()) can also be used. In particular, the docs say that parseInt() will take a hex string (it should begin with 0x to indicate a hex string).

Comment: @Abby Chau Yu Hoi No need to append 0x look edited answer parseInt() method. Probaly append 0x common practice.

Comment: @SunilD. Thanks for another approach (+1) it also great deal with conversion.