# Convert an signed int to 8 digit hex in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

How can i convert a type int into 8 digit hex decimal in flex

I need a function similiar in c# [ ToString("X8") ]. This function does the job in c#. 
But what is the option in flex ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert hex to decimal in Actionscript3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659322/how-to-convert-hex-to-decimal-in-actionscript3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the docs, it's pretty much the same:

```
var myInt:int = 255;
var hex:String = myInt.toString(16);
trace(hex);  //outputs "ff"
```

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html#toString()
If it's colors you're after: the docs describe how to handle that case too.

---

There is however no built-in way to add the leading zeros. You can use a method like this one to do that:

```
public function pad(s:String, pattern:String="0", minChars:int=8):String {
    while (s.length < minChars) s = pattern + s;
    return s;
}

trace(pad(hex)); //000000ff
```

Comment: If the int value is 131075,if i use the function above the return is 20003. But according to c# function it is 00020003 .That type of 8 digit result which i want...

Comment: @Nithil Edited with a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this is for 6 digit hex colors but could easily be modified to any number of hex digits.*

Found a lot of ways  of outputting padded hex values that relied heavily on string padding.

I wasn't really happy with any of those so this is what I came up with: (as a bonus it fits on one line)  You could even shorten it by removing the toUpperCase() call as case is really irrelevant.

```
"0x"+ (i+0x1000000).toString(16).substr(1,6).toUpperCase()
```

If you want to floor or ceiling that to black and white and put that in a function:

```
    public static function toHexColor(i:Number):String {
      return i<0 ? "0x000000" : i>0xFFFFFF ? "0xFFFFFF" : "0x"+ (i+0x1000000).toString(16).substr(1,6).toUpperCase() ;
    }
```

Here is a more expanded version with comments:

```
    public static function toHexColor(i:Number):String {
      //enforce ceiling and floor
      if(i>0xFFFFFF){ return "0xFFFFFF";}
      if(i<0){return "0x000000";}
      //add the "magic" number 
      i += 0x1000000;   
      //append the 0x and  strip the extra 1
      return "0x"+ i.toString(16).substr(1,6).toUpperCase();
    }
```